# Valid UUID django.core.exception

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an object with a parent field but I got a n error and don't know how to solve it?

```py
oblast_obj = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=oblast)
city_obj = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=city, parent=oblast_obj)
```

and when I'm creating `city_obj` the exception is:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'Волинська Обл.' is not a valid UUID."]
```

Comment: You need to show the model definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) method return two values `obj` -- the instance of the model and `created` boolean is object created. So you can try:

```
oblast_obj, created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=oblast)
city_obj, created = Place.objects.get_or_create(name=city, parent=oblast_obj)
```